# Flyway 7.7.3 seems to ignore my "callback"

Tags: flyway

I am upgrading from Flyway 5.4 to 7.7.3 and ran into some issue.

```
 flyway -teams -url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE "-user=xxx as SYSDBA" -password=xxx -table=flyway_schema_history_app -encoding=utf-8 -baselineOnMigrate=true migrate
```

(I have the teams edition license)

Flyway gives me the following error message:

**
ERROR: Unable to parse statement in /flyway/sql/incremental/Build_302_Baseline/V302_106__fosprd_INSERT_Master_eg_pocqueue.sql at line 117 col 1. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/knownparserlimitations for more information: No value provided for variable substitution: &R.  Check your configuration. If this is not a SQL*PLus variable intended to be substituted (eg. in a string literal), then you will need to add SET DEFINE OFF in the script beforehand.
Caused by: No value provided for variable substitution: &R.  Check your configuration. If this is not a SQL*PLus variable intended to be substituted (eg. in a string literal), then you will need to add SET DEFINE OFF in the script beforehand.
**

This is caused by a special character "&" in the SQL statement, however, I have made sure the SQL file is using UTF-8 encoding as well as Unix return (LF).

Also, I keep my callbacks under:

```
bash-5.0$ pwd
/flyway/sql/callbacks
bash-5.0$ ls
afterBaseline.sql       afterEachUndo.sql       afterMigrateError.sql   afterUndo.sql           beforeEachUndo.sql
afterBaselineError.sql  afterEachUndoError.sql  afterRepair.sql         afterUndoError.sql      beforeMigrate.sql
afterEachMigrate.sql    afterMigrate.sql        afterRepairError.sql    beforeEachMigrate.sql   beforeUndo.sql
```

This used to be able to run on 5.4 with no issue. But it's giving me this error on 7.7.3, anyone can point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Just to add to @madninja's answer, is the ampersand contained in a string literal? If not, could you provide a (redacted) SQL snippet?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the changes between versions of flyway's SQLPlus support and the fat you have a teams license.

As indicated in the message, this is related to SQLPlus's variable substitution:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle#variable-substitution

If you are not using SQLPlus features, you could try disabling them:
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/oracleSqlPlus
but the recommended solution is to place `SET DEFINE OFF` in the SQL script before the offending ampersand (with the option of reverting that afterwards)